# How can I run a robot test suite with Windows environment variable using pycharm terminal?

Tags: terminal, pycharm, environment-variables, robotframework

I setup an environment variable in Windows 10 called ROBOT_HOME and it points to my D:\Robot

When I run the test in my PyCharm terminal I use the following command -
robot --test "Example" %ROBOT_HOME%/test-cases

I require these environment variables as it is used company wide and they all call the same ROBOT_HOME and it needs to be defined in each Windows machine locally for it to work.

I am using the Intellibot@master.dev plugin in PyCharm.
It used to work until yesterday (as part of the robot course I'm going through, we used a diff robot framework plugin for PyCharm and now, even reverting back to the previous plugin, it won't work).
I keep getting "File Or Directory does not exist".
When I run the same command in command prompt, it works.
It used to work in the PyCharm terminal as well, not anymore.
In case it's worth mentioning, the PyCharm terminal is Windows Powershell.

Comment: Have you reeboot the computer?

Comment: Yes, the PC has gone through many reboots and the ROBOT_HOME environment variable was already working before.

Comment: In order to call an environment variable from the Powershell terminal in PyCharm, I needed to use the powershell env variable call -
$env:ROBOT_HOME
To see existing variable, can use the following command - dir env:

Answer (score 0):

In order to call an environment variable from the Powershell terminal in PyCharm, I needed to use the powershell env variable call -

```
$env:ROBOT_HOME
```

To see existing variable, can use the following command -

```
dir env:
```